# How to watch variables according to their content instead of their name?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, local-variables, javascript-debugger

I need to replace all variables that contains specific string or integer values with other values. For example, replace the value of all variables that contains`gnl.fr`with`nlg.com`.
In windbg *(windbg being attached to the web browser process)* this can be achieved like this :

```
.foreach (hit {s -[1]a 0 L?80000000 "gnl.fr"}) {ea ${hit} "nlg.com"}
```

However, it erase critical values from times to times, making the web browser crashing.
It should definitely be possible to do it at the JavaScript level instead of dealing with the web browser binary.

I don’t want to do it only for global variables, but everywhere it is possible *(I mean to include local variables from other JavaScript functions than the current one being debugged)*.

The problem is I don’t even know how to search in variables outside of the current scope.

**Before voting to close as unclear please pay attention to all the tags !**

Comment: Are the variables just strings, or are you also searching arrays and potentially deeply-nested objects?

Comment: The only variables you can access dynamically are global variables, since they're properties of `window`. There's no way to get all the local variables.

Comment: You need to do this dynamically in the script, not in the source code?

Comment: No need to close this. This is a perfectly acceptable question. It just need some attention.

Comment: @Barmar : no, as I said, this is need to be done with the JavaScript debugger.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What are you really trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Where does it say that in the question?

Comment: @Barmar : `Where does it say that in the question?`. Just look at the tags. It’s for debugging.

Comment: Even if you search memory with gdb, figuring out which Javascript variable that corresponds to will be quite difficult.

Comment: @Barmar : yeah, the JavaScript *(whether chrome or firefox)* debugger should already provide something simpler.

Comment: This is such an unusual thing to need to do, I can't imagine why it would already be provided.

Comment: What is it you're really trying to do, maybe we can suggest another approach?

Comment: If you want all accesses to www.gnl.fr to go to www.nlg.com, you could put an entry into your /etc/hosts file for www.gnl.fr with www.nlg.com's address.

Comment: @Barmar : `What are you really trying to accomplish with this?`reverse engineer a web site with a bug bounty program *(obfuscated code)*. Currently I’m using the tamperdata extension. The web app provide a registrar service which is still in beta. It seems they do only client side checks *(I already found the way to add existing domain names to the webcart)*. But when proceeding to payments, the browser starts a lot of xhr in for checking the domain is really available a second time *(each time with the domain name in post data)* which starts to make things too much.

Comment: Why don't you just intercept `XMLHttpRequest.send()` and search the data for the string you want to replace?

Comment: Opera Dragonfly have a search in all files feature. when I looked for the domain name I wanted to replace I got a single result in html. But replacing it isn’t enough.

Comment: @Barmar : `Why don't you just intercept XMLHttpRequest.send()`because the request parameters are set‑up *somewhere* by a parent function *(and I’m getting a 302 function large call stack)* . So you get the same problems than using the tamperdata browser extension *(changing the value 90 times for 90 requests)*. If I automatically replace all the strings during the purchase I wouldn’t have to do it again.

Comment: It sounds like the obfuscated code may have these strings encoded, and it's decoding them on the fly as it needs them. So it might not appear anywhere in the variables until the shortly before it uses them, and there's nothing to replace globally.

Comment: @Barmar : No, those strings are never sent obfuscated, so there are reason to believe they aren’t stored obfuscated. The best way to check it would be to try replacing everything.

Comment: I know they're not sent obfuscated, but I suspect they're de-obfuscated just before they're sent.

Comment: @Barmar : Ok, I took the hard [window memory way](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2012/02/21/windbg-search-for-a-string/) at each steps and it works. So the values are definitely not obfuscated. I’d still like a more friendly JavaScript debugger way, because I think It can be used to order domains with negative fees.

Comment: @ScottKaye : No your’re wrong, I want to replace the strings everywhere in memory, so it includes arrays and deeply-nested objects.

Comment: re: "_I don’t even know how to search in variables outside of the current scope_": that's because you can't. there are many strings that are un-reachable by anything but the original closured code.

Comment: @dandavis strangely,`info variables`give the value of all variables for all scope in gdb. Accessing values of all allocated variables is a feature of every well designed debugger *(I agree it requires special privileges but it need to be possible)*.

Comment: @user2284570 it may be possible to do the following: remove the included script file (find the script node in the document and remove it) and then manually load it's source with ajax request, perform the replace in the source text and then eval() it to apply the modified version.

Comment: @BorisSerebrov : The problem is they aren’t part of any script file. The functions I’m dealing with are injected ***somewhere*** by some javascript code which is itself injected from ***somewhere*** *(which means no idea from)*.

Comment: @user2284570 Can you create a stacksnippets or plnkr hhtp://plnkr.co to demonstrate?

Comment: @user2284570 Have you tried searching all loaded HTML/JS for occurrences? If you know where they're set and they're not obfuscated, you could target them directly?

Comment: @Paraknight : yes I did with the Opera dragonfly feature *(please read every comments first)*. Even inline javasvascript code doesn’t contains those values.

Comment: @guest271314 : no because I don’t control the code *(trying to reverse engineer a web application I don’t own)*. However, the windbg command should pretty much describe what I need *(though I only want variable contents instead of whole memory)*. basically, I’m trying to watch variables according to their contents instead of their names.

Comment: @user2284570 And yet you say that these strings aren't obfuscated? It's one or the other; either they're there or they're obfuscated (unless they're de-obfuscated run-time, in which case you can try to do the same during run-time).

Comment: @Paraknight : what I’m thinking is they are parsed from one of the many json files sent during initial page load. And I know that json file contains`"{\"2\":","{\"1\":9,\"2\":","\"120000000\"","{\"1\":8,\"2\":","\"108000000\"","{\"1\":\"USD\",","{\"1\":7,\"2\":","\"96000000\"","{\"1\":6,\"2\":","\"84000000\"","{\"1\":5,\"2\":","\"72000000\"","{\"1\":4,\"2\":","\"60000000\"","{\"1\":3,\"2\":","\"48000000\"","{\"1\":2,\"2\":","\"36000000\"","\"24000000\"","\"12000000\"`. But not any idea about it’s name.

Comment: However, I found chrome can [dump javascript heap to a file](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/heap-profiling). But the file is too much obfuscated to guess variable names. I have also no way to set the concerned local variables.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through each object and its children recursively. Modify specific children.
To prevent recursion related errors you can specify for how many levels you want to go into the child's children.

---

Further explanation in the comments of the following example:

```js
/**
Replace all strings from @inObj matching @toReplace with @replaceWith
*/

var replace = function(inObj, toReplace, replaceWith, optionalArguments){



  console.log("before", inObj);

  var recursion = function(obj, recursionLevel){

    if(typeof recursionLevel === 'undefined'){
      recursionLevel = 0;
    }

    recursionLevel++;

    if(typeof optionalArguments !== 'undefined'){
      if( typeof optionalArguments.maxRecursionLevel !== 'undefined' && recursionLevel > optionalArguments.maxRecursionLevel ){ // simply return the object if maxRecursionLevel reached
        return obj;
      }
    }

    for(var b in obj) { 
      if(typeof obj.hasOwnProperty !== 'undefined' && obj.hasOwnProperty(b)){
        if(typeof obj[b] === "string"){ // element is a string - here we do the actual work: replacing the strings
          obj[b] = obj[b].replace(toReplace, replaceWith);
        }else if(typeof obj[b] === "object" && obj[b]){ // element is an object - call as an object "recursively"
          obj[b] = recursion(obj[b], recursionLevel);
        }
      }
    }
    return obj;
  }

  inObj = recursion(inObj);
  console.log("after", inObj);
  return inObj;
}


/**
example for a test object
*/
var testObj = {
  a: "abc",
  b: "xyz",
  c: {
    aa: {
      aaa: "abc",
      bbb: "abc"
    },
    bb: "abc"
  },
  d: {
    aa: "abc"
  }
};

replace(testObj, /bc/i, "X", {maxRecursionLevel:2}); // for two levels
//replace(testObj, /bc/i, "X");  // for all levels



/**
example for the global scope
*/
//replace(window, /gnl.fr/i, "nlg.com");
```

Comment: I recognize searching into globals could be the first step. In my case, the value is in a parsed array from a Json file. So while it can be a global, How to walk through children objects of window ?

Comment: I updated my answer including an recursive approach which handles children, too.

Comment: Thanks, and how to handle TooMuchRecursion exeptions ? *(I mean skip object if the browser sends an error because the recursion is too deep)*. I would also like to not have a recursive function *(the call stack is limited to less than 1000 on chrome)*.

Comment: The problem is those errors can’t be caught with try/catch.

Comment: Now I have added support for a maximal recursion level

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113232/discussion-between-cocoseis-and-user2284570).